# ASP.NET Core Serilog to Loggly not showing json property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog, loggly

Our application uses the Serilog NuGet package to write logs to Loggly, and I am using `GlobalLogContext`to add a custom property like this:

```
using (GlobalLogContext.PushProperty("TransactionActivityId", activityId))
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Test log message");
}
```

We also set up the logger by doing

```
.UseSerilog((context, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
    .Enrich.FromGlobalLogContext())
```

In Loggly, I see the property in the "raw message" section, but the custom property is not showing up in the json section.
[image]

What has to be done in order for Loggly to show this property in the json section?

Comment: do you have the enrich bit wired up per https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-enrichers-globallogcontext ?

Comment: Yes. I followed those instructions and have `.Enrich.FromGlobalLogContext()`, and that was how I was able to get the property to show up in the "raw message" section. Sorry I shouldn't made that clear.

Comment: Apologies for not reading! I assume there is some whitelist somewhere that is lifting `SourceContext` into the highlghted/indexed properties; unfortunately I have zero knowledge of Loggly's config so can't say whether that's configured in Loggly or in the Loggly sink.

Comment: Funny thing is, if I had a structured message like `LogInformation("Test message {ActivityId}", activityId)`, the `activityId` gets picked up by loggly automatically and shows up as a property under json. But I don't want to include the activity Id in every message body.